# Project must provide a value for configuration

Tags: asp.net-core

Project must provide a value for configuration. Msbuild failed wih this error and its working fine if doing build via vs 2017. But breaking when using Msbuild cmdline

Comment: Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am not able to upload screenshot over there, but i was able to fix this. Actually dotnet core projects require a separate configuration other than release /debug or cpu platform. That is /p: targetffamework=netcoreapp(version of. Netcore your app is using).

Comment: Can someone please provide an answer explaining how to fix this please, I've ended up here trying to understand the same problem, and your one and only comment doesn't help very much.

Comment: @shawly try removing unused nuget package references

Comment: @shubhamarya can you please accept my answer ? ty

Answer (score 17):

Try deleting `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` in your `.csproj` file. That worked perfectly for me. I had the same issue, when I migrated my project from  `.NET Core 2.2` to `.NET Core 3.0`.

Comment: big thanks, deleting line with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" from project file fixed my problem.

Comment: worked! made my day!