# the project must provide a value for configuration Error when install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation in Core3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, runtime-compilation

When I install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** in a Web project and in Startup add :

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

,the project does not run and the error is:

> the project must provide a value for configuration

my .NET-Core version is 3.1

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you share  the package references of the project file?

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221807/88204

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some GitHub issues with this problem and some solutions that have worked for people. That said I would check to see that all NuGet packages are on versions supported by .NET Core 3.1. At this particular moment that means not too new so as to only work with .NET 5 and not too old so as to only work with Core 2.2.

Otherwise, someone suggested restarting VS.

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9932

You may also try deleting `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` from the CsProj file per [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356244/project-must-provide-a-value-for-configuration)

Comment: Deleting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design from the CsProj file did the trick for me. Thank You!